# Setting map view annotation properties

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkannotation

I am working on display a map with annotation on it. What I have so far is

**Annotation.h**

```
#import <MapKit/MKAnnotation.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Annotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> 

@end
```

**MapViewController.m**

```
Annotation *pin = [[Annotation alloc] init];    
[pin title]       = storeName;   
[pin subtitle]    = storeAddress;   
[pin coordinate]  = region.center;       
[mapView addAnnotation:pin];
```

However, I got an error like below:

> expression is not assignable for ***title, subtitle and coordinate***

Does anyone have any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, these lines try to assign a value to a method call which is what the error is saying you can't do:

```
[pin title]       = storeName;   
[pin subtitle]    = storeAddress;   
[pin coordinate]  = region.center;
```

They should be like this:

```
pin.title       = storeName;   
pin.subtitle    = storeAddress;   
pin.coordinate  = region.center;
```

However, the `MKAnnotation` protocol defines the properties as `readonly`.  To be able to set them, declare them in your `Annotation` class as:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
```

and add the `@synthesize` lines for them in `Annotation.m`.

However, if all you need are the `title`, `subtitle`, and `coordinate` properties, you don't need to create your own class to implement `MKAnnotation`.  Instead, just use the built-in `MKPointAnnotation` class which already implements those properties as settable:

```
MKPointAnnotation *pin = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
```

Another option, as @macbirdie points out, is just to make your existing `Store` class (if you have one) implement the `MKAnnotation` protocol.

Comment: I go for MKPointAnnotation after all. Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1):

Just read the documentation on [MKAnnotation protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). You're not supposed to assign the title, subtitle and coordinate. You have to provide an implementation of these methods in your class conforming to this protocol.

So it's better if you create a `StoreAnnotation` class that receives storeName, storeAddress and storeCoordinates, or simply a Store class if you have any, and it will return appropriate data in the protocol methods.

Comment: but i think these variables are attribute not method, rite ?... so how can we implement them

Comment: They are methods as you can see in protocol's reference. And you implement them just like any other objective-c instance method.

Comment: i went to MKAnnotation protocol  and click on  Jump To, there are Properties and Instance Methods. In Properties, they are title, subtitle and coordinate...

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry. They're read only though. That was the general idea. There's only setCoordinate method in addition to those properties. You have to implement this one as well, anyway.